# Configuring SSL in Apache HttpAsyncClient

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I need to setup an Apache HTTPAsyncClient with SSL support. I use this code, but it doesn't seem to work (getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure")

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake");
    System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ts.load(loadStream("C:/TrustStore/cacerts"), "trustpass".toCharArray());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(loadStream("C:/KeyStore/SSL/keystore.SomeKey"), "keypass".toCharArray());

    SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(ts).loadKeyMaterial(ks, "somekey".toCharArray()).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());        
    SSLContext ssl = sslBuilder.build();

    PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT));        

    CloseableHttpAsyncClient clientHttps = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)    
            .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
            .setSSLContext(ssl)
            .build();

    RequestConfig.Builder b = RequestConfig.custom();        
    b.setProxy(new HttpHost("proxyHost", proxyPort));
    RequestConfig rc = b.build();

    clientHttps.start();

    HttpRequestBase req = new HttpPost("https://someurl");
    ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase)req).setEntity(new StringEntity("somestring"));
    req.setConfig(rc);

    clientHttps.execute(req, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void failed(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse result) {
            System.out.println(result);                
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            System.out.println("Cancelled");                
        }
    });
```

When using the javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection to achive this, it works (I can attach the relevant code, if needed).

**EDIT**

Based on @ben75 answer, I finally make it running with the following code

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake");
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");

KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ts.load(loadStream("C:/TrustStore/cacerts"), "trustpass".toCharArray());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(loadStream("C:/KeyStore/SSL/keystore.SomeKey"), "keypass".toCharArray());

SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(ts).loadKeyMaterial(ks, "somekey".toCharArray()).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());        
SSLContext ssl = sslBuilder.build();

SSLIOSessionStrategy s = new SSLIOSessionStrategy(ssl, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
RegistryBuilder<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> rb = RegistryBuilder.create();
rb.register("https", s).register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE);
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT), rb.build());       

CloseableHttpAsyncClient clientHttps = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();

RequestConfig.Builder b = RequestConfig.custom();        
b.setProxy(new HttpHost("proxyHost", proxyPort));
RequestConfig rc = b.build();

clientHttps.start();

HttpRequestBase req = new HttpPost("https://someurl");
((HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase)req).setEntity(new StringEntity("somestring"));
req.setConfig(rc);

clientHttps.execute(req, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void failed(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void completed(HttpResponse result) {
        System.out.println(result);                
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {
        System.out.println("Cancelled");                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I run in very similar problem recently (on Android) but I guess you are making the same error as I did.)

When you set a connection manager explicitly : `builder.setConnectionManager(cm)` the sslContext is ignored.

What you can do is inject your SSLContext in the PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.

To do so, you can use this constructor :
[PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ConnectingIOReactor ioreactor, Registry iosessionFactoryRegistry)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/nio/conn/PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.html#PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ConnectingIOReactor,%20org.apache.http.config.Registry))

with iosessionFactoryRegistry containing an [SSLIOSessionStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/nio/conn/ssl/SSLIOSessionStrategy.html#SSLIOSessionStrategy(javax.net.ssl.SSLContext)) build with your SSLContext

Comment: Thank you @ben75. Just to complete your answer, I had to add some more lines (edited question).

Comment: @MetaHnet You are welcome. I just edited your question to keep both version of the code so that question and answer are still meaningful to future readers

Comment: @ben75 I have a specific situation where I call different endpoints (some with sslContext and some without sslContext). And this will be decided at runtime, so I can't prebuild sslContext and assign it to PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager. What should be the approach for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
public SSLContext getSSLContext() {
    final TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
    try {
        final SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();
        sslContext.getServerSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1000);
        return sslContext;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> getSSLRegistryAsync() {
    return RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>create()
            .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
            .register("https", new SSLIOSessionStrategy(
                    getSSLContext(), null, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)).build();
}

public PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager getPoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager() {
    try {
        final PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
                new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT), getSSLRegistryAsync());
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(connectionPoolMax);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(connectionPoolMaxPerRoute);

        return connectionManager;
    } catch (IOReactorException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

public RequestConfig getRequestConfig() {
    return RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
            .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(socketTimeout)
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.IGNORE_COOKIES)
            .build();
}

public CloseableHttpAsyncClient getHttpAsyncClient() {
    final CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(getPoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(getRequestConfig())
            .build();
    return httpAsyncClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My example in asynchronous mode:

```
     try {
         SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext(X509Cert);

         CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = getHttpAsyncClient(sslContext,HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_POOL_CONNECTIONS,HTTP_CLIENT_MAX_PER_ROUTE_CONN);
         setHttpAsyncClient(httpAsyncClient);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Generic SSL Error Adapter: {} - {}", e.getMessage(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}


private SSLContext getSSLContext(X509CertificateValidator trustStrategy) {
    try {
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy)
                .build();
        sslContext.getServerSessionContext().setSessionCacheSize(1000);
        return sslContext;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException e) {
        LOG.error("SSL Context creation error: {} - {}", e.getMessage(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}


private Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> getSSLRegistryAsync(SSLContext sslContext) {
    Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> defaultRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> create()
            .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
            .register("https", new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
            .build();

    return defaultRegistry;

}

private PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager getPoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(SSLContext sslContext, int connectionPoolMax, int connectionPoolMaxPerRoute) {
    try {
        PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager =
                new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT), getSSLRegistryAsync(sslContext));
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(connectionPoolMax);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(connectionPoolMaxPerRoute);
        return connectionManager;
    } catch (IOReactorException e) {
        LOG.error("NHttp Connectio Manager error: {} - {}", e.getMessage(), e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}


public CloseableHttpAsyncClient getHttpAsyncClient(SSLContext sslContext, int connectionPoolMax, int connectionPoolMaxPerRoute) {
    final CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(getPoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(sslContext, connectionPoolMax, connectionPoolMaxPerRoute))
            //.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
    return httpAsyncClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of great answers here but as of writing this answer, I found a lot of convenient builders in the httpcomponents library. For eg, in order to create a trust all based sslcontext, I used to following:

```
HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                    .setConnectionManager(PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                            .setTlsStrategy(ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
                                    .setSslContext(SSLContextBuilder.create()
                                            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy())
                                            .build())
                                    .build())
                            .build())
                    .build()
```